# How to end AudioPlayer player when audio is done

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, audio-player

How do I detect when audio is done playing to call `AudioPlayer.stop()` so that it can be played again in the python [AudioPlayer](https://pypi.org/project/audioplayer/#API) library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the `block` parameter to True so the `play` function will return once playback is done (as stated by the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/audioplayer/#API))

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to check the length of the audio and then use the threading library's `wait` function to wait until the song is over. Definitely not the most efficient option but here's how I did it:

```
from audioplayer import AudioPlayer
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import threading
import random
import os


event = threading.Event()
funcAplayer = AudioPlayer('Audio/'+(random.choice(os.listdir('Audio/'))))


def function_a():  # A
    funcAplayer.play(loop=False, block=False)
    audio = MP3(funcAplayer.filename)
    event.wait(int(audio.info.length + 0.05))
    funcAplayer.stop()
```

I added a fraction of a second onto the end so that there's a slight delay, making spam less spammy but it's not necessary.